# Make Flash DRM work in Windows Chromium

Tags: windows, google-chrome, flash

We want to switch from Google Chrome to Chromium on Windows 10 and one of the requirements is to have Flash DRM working.

These are the steps that i followed in order to make it work:

1. Install Chromium 69.0.3497.100 with Widevine and codecs support from:
   https://chromium.woolyss.com/f/chrlauncher-win64-stable-codecs-sync.zip
2. Open Google Chrome and load `chrome://flash` to copy `pepflashplayer.dll` path & version
3. Open chromium with `--ppapi-flash-path=$PATH_TO_pepflashplayer.dll --ppapi-flash-version=$DLL_VERSION` arguments
4. Open `chrome://flash` in Chromium to ensure it looks exactly as Chrome
5. Open http://drmtest2.adobe.com:8080/SVP/SampleVideoPlayer_FP.html and try to load http://drmtest2.adobe.com:8080/Content/anonymous.f4v
6. Flash works, but the movie does not play as displays Error 3307 (DRM error)
7. I also tried to download flash PPAPI from Adobe, but got the same result.

If I try to play the same video in Chrome, works perfectly. What am I missing? Why is chrome able to play the drm while chromium does not?

Comment: What version of Chrome are you currently using?  I thought Chrome discontinued support for the ppapi Flash add-on over 2 years ago.

Comment: Did you try the normal method to install flash in Chromium?

Answer (score 0):

I had to install flash from the official Adobe site - https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/. Once it was installed, DRM flash videos work. I didn't add any of the Widevine or Codex. I loaded the drmtest site (pop asked if I would like to allow the flash plug-in, I answered in the affirmative), entered the URL referenced above and it played.

Comment: I forgot to say that i also tried that, both with 32b & 64b. And then pointing to C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash\pepflashplayer.....dll. And didn't work, flash does but not it's DRM :( Did you set any argument on chromium startup?